# Difference in meaning between "Ça ne sert à rien de..." and "Rien ne sert de..."

Tags: expressions

> **Ça ne sert à rien d**'alimenter les ragots de l'école.
>
> **Rien ne sert d**'alimenter les ragots de l'école.

I wonder if there is any notable difference between the two constructions.

Incidentally, is "Ça ne rime à rien de..." synonymous with "Ça ne sert à rien de..."?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No notable difference.

The second is kind of old-fashioned and the only exemples that come in mind are proverbs like « Rien ne sert de courir, il faut partir à point. » − La Fontaine

More generaly, the second is rarely (never?) used without another proposition after,  whereas the first could be a sentence alone.

And whatever is the proposition after you could still use the first construction, which is, again, more common nowaday.

> "Ça ne rime à rien de..." synonymous with "Ça ne sert à rien de..."?

Absolutly. Exact same meaning. I don't know the reason and I can't find any other verbe than "rimer" that could fit here (to replace 'sert')…

Comment: Merci. Does the following phrase have a slightly different meaning: "Ça ne **nous avance/avancera** à rien de..."?

Comment: @LUNA they both convey the same meaning

Comment: I wouldn't say the second is never used but it's indeed more formal and old-fashioned. It is therefore used to give some style to a speach or a text, while the first would look a bit incongruous in written languague from where I see it.

Comment: @Laurent S.    Merci. I'm a little confused as to what "the first" and "the second" in your comment each refer to. Are you mentioning "avance" versus "avancera", or "servir" versus "avance/avancera"? Actually, I wanted to find out if "servir", "rimer", and "avancer" all mean the same thing in this usage, or if they are nuanced in meaning? Thanks.

Comment: @LUNA my second comment wasn't for you but for stéphane

Comment: @LUNA first and second refer to your examples. And yeah, "avancer" is right and have the exact same meaning (in this context).